# Divide and conquer find value?

Tags: c, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

A[1,2,3,..,n] is ordered array. Find if A[i]==i return i else return 0 with divide and conquer algorithm.

example:
first call -> find(A,1,n)

A[3]={1,2,3}

if A[2]==2 return value

else return 0

i tried this it's not exactly working

```
partition(int A[],int p,int q){
    int x=3;
    int i=p;
    int j=p+1;
    for(j;j<q;j++)
    {
        if(A[j]==x){
            i++;
            printf("true");
        }
        
    }
    printf("false");
    return i;
}

find(int A[],int p,int q){
    if(p<q){
        int r=partition(A,p,q);
        return find(A,r+1,q);
        return find(A,p,r-1);
    }   
}
int main ()
{
    int A[5]={1,9,3,7,5};
    
    find(A,1,3);
    
}
```

Comment: Remember that `return` returns from the function *immediately*. Having a second `return` statement right after the first one will not execute it. If you enable more warning a decent compiler will be able to warn you about that (and *many* other things).

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to [edit] your question to improve it. For example, don't tag multiple languages, only the language the shown code is written in. And note that your code is really invalid in both C and C++. And lastly, what does `find` return if `if(p<q)` is *false*?

Comment: How does matching elements with 3 find the one that equals it's index? How is that partitioning the array? Sounds to me `partition` should just be `std::midpoint`. And you are supposed to do the actual finding in find in the `else` branch of your if.